Why does negative particle "not" directly located after preopsition "to"?
I am studying english language at the present moment and now I am reading texts in Starlight book for the 8th grade. I came upon such sentence:

Why does negative particle "not" stand after preposition "to"? I think it would be right as follows:
One way to deal with these kinds of people is not to get involved in whatever thet are talking about: stay neutral ot admit to seeing both sides of an issue.
Are sentence in the text and mine equivalent or not?
